# Outline property is not working in IE

Tags: css, internet-explorer, outline

I have added outline for my table rows. It's working fine on Chrome and Firefox. However this does not produce the expected output on IE.
On IE, outline is only displayed when I click on the row otherwise its not displaying.

CSS which I have added for rows:

```
outline: dashed 2px #9e0b0f;
```

If I use border means, On IE its working perfect.But on chrome and firefox dashed lines are not that much clear it is displayed as straight line.
[image]

sample fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/r8bqLsqp/

How can I get the correct output in IE?

Comment: you can use the `border` for this and you will get the same result and if you can please paste a snippet of your code so we can see what you are trying to achieve. usually `outline` works fine.

Comment: Which version you are using of IE?

Comment: @JithinRajPR If I use border means, On `IE` its working perfect.But on `chrome` and `firefox` dashed lines are not that much clear it is displayed as straight line.

Comment: @RohitVerma IE 11.

Comment: @krish can you please paste a code `fiddle` or `snippet` so we can check why are you facing this issue. I usually use `border` on my projects and it usually turns up great on all browsers.

Comment: @krish Can you please add minimal HTML/CSS code that reproduces your issue? I see that outline works perfectly in IE https://jsfiddle.net/uw9b72v8/.

Comment: @krish it's working on IE 11 can you show your entire code where do you want to add this.

Comment: @krish I've tested your jsFiddle in IE and see that it's working fine.

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov ok fine.I think only my main project has problem I will check it once again.